# Transfer the configuration settings and data from HPRM production to test

Tags: hp, trim

We are performing an upgrade of HPRM and we want to be able to replicate the production environment into a new test environment in AWS. Our infrastructure in AWS is already set up, however we were wondering if there was a way to export all the configurations and records from the production environment so we can import it into our new test enthronement.

Our current version of HPRM is 8.1.0.7517